# Jupyter Notebook - Terminal error - Powershell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

Getting below error while launching Jupyter notebook terminal.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https:aka.ms//pscore6
Attempting to perform initialize default drives operation on the filesystem provider failed.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is typically displayed by PowerShell when you either do not have access (e.g. due to permissions) to some of your drives or have something like SoftGrid installed.

Please refer to the below articles:

https://www.techtalkz.com/threads/initializedefaultdrives-error-message-on-startup.180540/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/